# does using wordpress outside wordpress installation makes site slower?

Tags: outside-wordpress

I have already seen that we can call wordpress outside wordpress installation. but I am always curious if this approach cause website to load slow. I don't want to enable multisite. Is there anyone willing to guide me.

Comment: Slower than what? Loading WordPress is obviously slower than not loading WordPress. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: i just want to use wordpress outside wordpress installation. Is there any better way to achieve this??

Comment: Achieve _what_?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lets say, you want to create a website in php or html, css and javascript that doesnt use wordpress, thats ok, you can do it.
But you wanna use wordpress things like products or posts or images, and for this you will use wordpress api to load them in your website that isnt a wordpress plataform.
this is alright, you have your website that uses wordpress api only, not the wordpress by itself.  if is slower or not will depend of the servers you have.
the server where you have your wordpress with the database and the server where you have your website wordpress free that uses only wordpress api.
but lets say we are making a comparison with the same servers.
you have two websites, the website one that is a wordpress website  and the website two that uses only the wordpress api to get the things.
who is fastest.
I really dont know, never try it, never saw no one do this, but it is possible.
the website one has to load wordpress plataform, but has the database in the same server.
the website two doesnt need to load wordpress plataform, so here is possibly faster, but then has to get the things with wordpress api.
Good question, when you find out, give some feedback

Comment: Sure. Thanks for your reply